# How to customise (add properties to) existing Blender data?

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to to customise Blender specific data structures?
For example how could I add a python `list` data type to a Blender `action`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [CollectionProperty](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.props.html#collection-example) to store a variable amount of items like a list, the properties per item need to be declared beforehand:

```
import bpy

class VectorPropGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # name = StringProperty() # this is inherited from bpy.types.PropertyGroup
    vector = bpy.props.IntVectorProperty(size=3)

bpy.utils.register_class(VectorPropGroup)

bpy.types.Action.my_collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=VectorPropGroup)

action = bpy.data.actions.new("My Action")

item = action.my_collection.add()
item.name = "First"
item.vector = (1,2,3)

item = action.my_collection.add()
item.name = "Second"
item.vector = (2,3,4)

print(action.my_collection[0].name, action.my_collection[0].vector[:])
print(action.my_collection[1].name, action.my_collection[1].vector[:])
```

It will print:

```
First (1, 2, 3)
Second (2, 3, 4)
```

Note that you can't `add()` items from within a `draw()` method. You need to call it manually (text editor / Python console) or create an operator for the user to be used in a UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize data structures with **custom properties**.

Note that only **bpy.types.ID**, **bpy.types.Bone** and **bpy.types.PoseBone** classes support custom properties.

**bpy.types.ID subclasses**: *WindowManager, Speaker, MetaBall, ParticleSettings, Palette, PaintCurve, Camera, GreasePencil, NodeTree, Material, Mask, Lamp, Sound, Object, Library, Screen, MovieClip, Brush, Mesh, FreestyleLineStyle, Scene, Text, Curve, Lattice, Texture, Image, Armature, Key, Group, VectorFont, Action, World*

So **Yes**, *Action will support custom properties*

There are several types of custom properties: [*static*, *dynamic* and *ID*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties)

For **static type** the format to store lists in is for example bpy.props.StringProperty(), so any data needs to be encoded into string and then decoded.

For **ID type** you can use lists and dictionaries but lists may only contain floats and integers. Also they are declared only for single datablock.

The *dynamic* accept functions and are not stored with blend file.

Comment: How is `StringProperty` a list format? The only real list type is `CollectionProperty`.

Comment: I meant like you can store lists in them. CollectionProperty is finite. I will edit to make it clear

Comment: You can basically add as many items to a collection as you want, or did you find an upper limit?

Comment: You can add as many of items at collection declaration, yes. But you cant add dynamically more or remove. You would have to create a new collection and swap it. The collection is meant to represent finite collection of properties and such behavior would confuse the code reader. Encoding a new string and adding it to old one when list grows (or truncating it) and swapping strings is far more convenient don't you think? If the encoding/decoding is well designed it shouldn't be even a performance bottleneck.

Comment: I don't think you got that right, collections **are** dynamic. After declaration, they contain zero elements. What properties the `PropertyGroup` has (so every item in the collection) can't be changed after declaration indeed, but that shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: You are right, the method `add()` (which is not very well documented or exampled) works outside of `draw()`. That's nice and thanks for the info. This should be at least put inside code example in here: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html#bpy.types.PropertyGroup. Do you know someone that can change it?

Comment: There is an example on the bpy.props page: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.props.html#collection-example